# How can I automate the test plan creation in SAP SolMan?

Tags: abap, sap-solution-manager

Currently I am trying to create an ABAP program in SAP Solution Manager which will automatically create a test plan and test packages based on an excel file I have the project structure I have created previously. Is there any documentation, API etc. available for this which documents where I can find the relevant data. I have found a few tables like TNODE02_A, which contains my test cases.

But where can I find the tables containing the test plans and test packages? I appreciate any input as I am completely new to SAP and ABAP.